# Applying (shift || '.') to a variable

Tags: perl

I am currently learning perl and when I encountered a piece of code explainng how to traverse a directory tree using recursive subroutines. This is the code in question

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
my $path = shift || '.';
traverse($path);

sub traverse {
my ($thing) = @_;

    return if not -d $thing;
    opendir my $dh, $thing or die;
    while (my $sub = readdir $dh) {
        next if $sub eq '.' or $sub eq '..';
        say "$thing/$sub";
        traverse("$thing/$sub");
    }
    close $dh;
    return;
}
```

I understood the subroutine and how it works, however I did not understand this statement:
(my $path = shift || '.';)
I know that it is the variable that is passed to the subroutine, but I do not know what value it takes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of a subroutine, `shift` with no arguments does `shift @ARGV`, getting the first command-line argument.

The `||` operator returns the left side if the left side is truthy or the right side if the left side is falsy.  So if the `shift` succeeded, `$path` probably gets set to the command-line argument.  If `@ARGV` was empty, `shift` returns `undef`, so `$path` will get set to `'.'` instead.

Note this will do the wrong thing if for example you have a directory named "0" and try to run `myscript.pl 0`.

Answer (score 0):

That statement says: "pull the next element from the argument list and assign it to `$path`. If there is no argument in the list, or the first element evaluates to false, put `.` in `$path` instead".

`shift`, when used in the main part of a program and not in a subroutine uses `@ARGV` (command line arguments) as its list to `shift` elements off of.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = shift || 'bye';

print "$x\n";
```

Run it:

```
$ perl script.pl
bye

$ perl script.pl hi
hi
```